# Max Number of Feature Selection in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, select-by-location, limitations

What are the limitations on the maximum number of features that you can select in ArcGIS?

Comment: This is really two different questions, and to the best of my knowledge, the answer is "all of them".  Please **edit** the question to expand upon your meaning.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you're running into?

Comment: While maybe not limitations, the behavior will differ based on what data sources you are  using. For example, ArcGIS will use temporary tables on within the database to store very large selections made against an Oracle SDE feature class.  That threshold is configurable though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with local data, then you can select any number of features. You may need a lot of RAM if you're working with millions of features.

If you're working with remote data on ArcGIS Server, then that number is set by the map publisher. That can be changed when publishing a MXD and changing the setting under the Parameters tab:

[image: publish]