# Select Widget not selecting all features inside polygon ArcGIS WebApp

Tags: arcgis-online, select-by-location, arcgis-web-appbuilder

AGOL version 8.4 - ArcGIS Web AppBuilder - Select Widget

I am trying to select a large number of point features using the Select Widget inside an ArcGIS web app. The number of features returned is smaller than the number that should be selected, and when zooming in the selection pattern appears random. Why are some features being selected and others not? Zoomed in  image shows the unselected points... Is there a threshold that can be set, perhaps in the original sharing/hosting stage?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the Max Number of Returned Records for the service in Server Manager or during the publishing process
See: [Max Number of Feature Selection in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160073/max-number-of-feature-selection-in-arcgis)